# Second most recent list item Haskell

Tags: haskell

I am trying to get the second item in a list in Haskell.  I would assume the best way to do this is to get the head of the tail of a list.

```
secondMostRecentChoice :: History -> Choice // a choice is just a Bool like Bake | NoBake
secondMostRecentChoice [] = "Not Enough History"
secondMostRecentChoice history = 
    if ( length history == 1 ) 
        then "Still Not Enough History"
    else if (length history >= 2)
        then (head [b | (head a,b) <- history]) //Here is the problem
        else "Not supposed to be here"
    else "Not supposed to be here"
```

but I get the following:

> > Parse error in pattern: head
> >         Possibly caused by a missing 'do'?

Why do I need to do a `do` or is that a false suggestion?

Comment: yes it is a false suggestion. you could write what you wanted as `head [b | (a:b:_) <- history]` — `a` is already a "head". But you should *never* measure `length` of a list if you can avoid it. And here you can avoid it, by just defining your function itself as a pattern match (a.o.t. your use of pattern match inside a list comprehension), as some answers suggest.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would use pattern matching, as it is clearer what the failure modes are:

```
   second :: [a] -> a
   second []      = error "Empty list"
   second [x]     = error "Singleton list"
   second (_:x:_) = x
```

Clearer, no? Makes the specification obvious.

Comment: Isn't the fact that `head` is `[a] -> a` and not `Maybe a` an oversight? I am kind of surprised seeing you `error` in this case.

Comment: @BartekBanachewicz It just means that if the list is too small it will cause an exception that can only be caught in the IO monad.  Although it does give much better error message reporting than `Maybe a` would give.

Comment: Why not `Either String a`, or whatever generic `MonadError` then? I wouldn't like to drag this comment thread too much, but this seems puzzling.

Comment: @BartekBanachewicz I guess it's just what was easier to type out on the SO answer box.  It could easily be re-factored with `s/error/fail/` and `s/= x/= return x/`

Comment: There's no specification. Using pattern matching makes it clear where the holes in the specification are. Those holes could be filled with Either or Maybe.

Answer (score 9):

The shortest way to do that is to just pattern match it.

```
secondElem :: [a] -> Maybe a
secondElem (_:x:_) = Just x
secondElem _       = Nothing
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to get the second item is to use the `!!` infix operator. It lets you access a particular item in a list. Normally, for most lists this would be too slow, but because it is only the second item, it doesn't really matter.

Comment: If the list is smaller than 2 elements this will give a confusing error message.

Comment: I had meant for him to use it after he had determined that the list was at least 2 elements long.

Comment: But how do you do that without walking the length of the list (adding useless overhead) as would happen with the `length` function?

Comment: That's a good point. I'm not an expert in this, of course, but it simply seemed to be the easiest way to get the second element would be to use the operator for getting the second element.

Comment: That's true.  It is definitely the easiest (one line instead of the two or three of the other solutions).